# Can we efficiently decompose $n=ab$ given a "zero polynomial" modulo $n$?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-factorization

Suppose that a polynomial $p=\sum_{0\leq j<n} u_jx^j$ with coefficients $0\leq u_j<n$ is constantly 0 modulo some $n$. If $n$ is a prime number, then $u=0$, because the Lagrange polynomials of degree $n-1$ form a basis and the coefficients of $p$ in that basis evaluate to 0. If $u\neq0$, then contrapositively $n$ is decomposable. Is there an efficient technique for finding such $a$ and $b$, that $n=ab$?

By efficient, I mean that it should be applicable to RSA numbers $n$ such as
$$\begin{align}\text{RSA}_{230} = &1796949159794106673291612844957324615636756180801260007088891883553172646\\&0341490933493372247868650755230855864199929221814436684722874052065257937\\&4956943483892631711525225256544109808191706117425097024407180103648316382\\&88518852689\end{align}$$
with a week of computing time on a personal computer, assuming we are given $p$ in a sparse format with a small number of nonzero coefficients $u_j\neq0$, say $10^6$.

Comment: You call the polynomial both $p$ and $u$.

Comment: I think I am calling the polynomial $p$ and its coefficients in the standard basis $u$.

Comment: More importantly, $x^{n} - x$ evaluates to zero modulo $n$ for all integers $x$ if $n$ is prime.

Comment: There is some sloppiness in your notation: is $u$ a vector of coefficients **mod n** (the reduced coefficients) or the original coefficients? $3x$ gives the zero polynomial modulo $3$ but $u_1\neq0$.

Comment: Based on your comments, I have added stricter ranges to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer is if all coefficients are $0$, assuming this is not the case,

then it could happen just if the power $j$ and the power $i$ which differ by $\phi(n)$ which is Euler totient function have the same coefficient meaning that $p= \cdots + u_j *x^j+ \cdots +u_i *x^i$ and $j-i = \phi(n)$ then $u_i = \pm u_j \mod n$ so you look at the polynomial and see a periodicity that tells you what $\phi(n)$ is and then by Fermat's little theorem and GCD(greates common divisor) you can factor $n$, how you get this amazing polynomial $p$ is another matter.

read about the discrete logarithm problem (open problem) to grasp how hard it would be to find such polynomial.

Example : for $n=77$ the polynomial $p=3 x^{61}+74*x$ which yield $0 \mod 77$ for any input $x$, so by the difference of the powers we can compute that $\phi(77)=60$ and use any one of the hundreds of algorithms that when given $\phi(n)$ factorize $n$.

Note : two important thing i found $p$ for $n=77$ because i computed $\phi(77)$ first (i worked backward lol).

secondly $p$ could have $2$ or $4$ or $6$ and so on terms.

another example for $n=77$ is the polynomial $p= 5*x^{65}+3*x^{61}-5*x^5+74*x$

Comment: Wow, that's impressive! How do you prove it?

Comment: Another example: $20x+14x^3+x^7$ modulo 35. Here's a basis of "zero polynomials" modulo 35, one per row, http://pastebin.com/EyRTc0jh.

Comment: @Joel Sjögren read about integer factorization and  about the  Euler totient function, also because $x^{\phi(n)}=1$ so when you multiple $x^4$ for say $n=77$ by $x^{60}$ you don't change the result $\mod 77$. its called Fermat little theorem that if gcd(a,n)=1 then $a^{\phi(n)} = 1 \mod n$

Comment: Basic facts about Euler's totient function make your argument reasonable, but logically the implications you are making seem to go in the wrong direction. Yes, often $x^{\phi(n)}=1$, but why does that mean you can derive $\phi(n)$ by looking for the pattern $u_i(x^i-x^j)\;(u_i\neq0)$ in a polynomial with much more than 2 nonzero coefficients?

Comment: In the case of $20x+14x^3+x^7$ modulo 35, the exponent differences are 2, 4 and 6. These are divisors of $\phi(35)=24$. Good! According to your method, do I need to derive $\phi(35)$ from them somehow? How do I know in general that all the exponent differences I get must be divisors of $\phi(n)$?

Comment: @Joel Sjögren well not exactly you will always get $\phi(n)$ you get a number that sure divide $\phi(n)$ for $\phi(35)=24$ you are right, but in the difference of $7-1=6$ and $3-0=0$ which divide $24$, also i did not mention that the way a produce a polynomial for an integer $n$ is the only way to produce a polynomial that satisfy your condition.

Comment: @Joel Sjögren it must happen to one factor or the other or to the whole number, any way it happens, you can easily factor $n$ by taking $GCD(r \pm 1,n)$ where $r$ is the remainder form taking some $a$ to the power of any periodicity you find in such polynomials

Comment: @Joel Sjögren i worked on this problem couple of years in university, i am not expert on the problem, but i think if there is a method that could factorize any integer it will be related to polynomials  $ \mod n$

Comment: You have explained the technique clearly enough (I didn't say algorithm) and the steps are efficient (gcd, powers etc) so I will accept this answer. Thank you for your insight!